# Dispersive wave and wavelength

Tags: waves, frequency, wavelength, dispersion

Suppose that we have a dispersive medium, for which it is  established that
$$\frac{\omega}{k\sqrt{1+a^2k^2}}=v.$$

That tells us that if $a>1$ then as the frequency of the wave gets higher and higher and then the velocity of this specific frequency gets bigger and bigger. But what happens with respect to the wavelength at this frequency? Now the velocity of each frequency is unique, so how am I supposed to determine its wavelength?

Comment: Can you not just use the product of the wavelength times the frequency equals the velocity?

Comment: What velocity are you giving? You need to be aware that for dispersive waves one distinguishes between phase velocity $v_p = \frac{\omega}{k}$ and group velocity $v_g = \frac{\text{d}\omega}{\text{d}k}$. For the former you could indeed do what @GrapefruitIsAwesome suggests.

Answer (score 2):

The velocity you provide cannot be the phase velocity, $\omega/k$, since then *a* =0, and you would not be talking about dispersion. So I gather you are giving the group velocity,
$$
{d\omega \over dk}= \frac{\omega}{k\sqrt{1+a^2k^2}},
$$
whose solution for the dispersion relation is, up to an additive  constant,
$$
\ln \omega= C - \operatorname{arctanh} \sqrt{1+a^2 k^2}.
$$

You may now substitute the answer in your expression and monitor $\lambda =2\pi/k$. Be advised this is a very weird dispersion relation.